# Website not working on mobile. WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have a problem in a client's web page. He has 4.7.4–es_ES version of Wordpress and I'm using the Divi framework (elegant themes) on its latest version: 3.0.44.

On PC screen the website works perfectly but when you enter the website on a mobile phone it doesn't work. The menu doesn't work, you cannot see the images and the blog posts are not updated.

You can only appreciate this if you enter the website with a real mobile phone. If you use the mobile console on Chrome or firefox it works perfectly.

Site: http://centromindfulnessmadrid.com/

Elegant themes site: https://www.elegantthemes.com/

Comment: Have you assigned a mobile menu?

Comment: Yes, in fact, if you click on the shopping cart icon (on mobile you can see the shopping cart icon and the menu icon), the website works perfectly. So I think it's something related to the index.

Comment: jquery script error in your site. fix the jquery script error. you can check by resize the browser window size below 768 check the menu. It wont work in desktop also.

Comment: Why do you have a cart? I can't find anywhere where you can add something to the cart?

Comment: @vel ok, I'll check the jquery error.

Comment: @Stender yes it has products. It's not an ecommerce but it sells courses. However those courses are not on home.

Comment: @vel I checked the website by resizing the browser window size and I didn't see any jquery error. Can you be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: seems your site working fine.

Comment: @vel yes, now the site is working perfectly. Thanks!